# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre value y [value] en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy trabajando con un codigo ya realizado haciendo algunos cambios y en algunas partes se utiliza value y en otras [value], cuales son las diferencias y cuando deberia usarse cada una?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la sintaxis de las vistas de Angular existen dos formas de pasar un valor a un componente:

```
<MyComponent param="valor1"></MyComponent>
```

De este modo al componente le estás pasando el literal `'valor1'`, un string.

```
<MyComponent [param]="valor1"></MyComponent>
```

De este modo al componente le estás pasando el valor del atributo `valor1` de tu componente.

Luego está la opción de relacionar la propiedad "en ida y vuelta" (*two way binding*):

```
<MyComponent [(param)]="valor1"></MyComponent>
```

Aquí la asociación va un paso más alla, y si el componente MyComponent modifica el valor de su input `param`, este cambio se verá reflejado en la propiedad `valor1`.